# Images of UITableView Cells change?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4.2, itunes, ios5

While i finished developing an in-app-purchase application, and after several testing on iPad/Iphone, every thing was fine, the images of table view's cells and its hight was exactly as wrote in code, so i upload the application, when it was processed to the app Store, i download it, the table view cells in both IPhone/IPad were in different sizes much bigger size  then that was set while testing,so the image in cells was like stretched!!!!and not clear, i tried to test it then directly via xcode to my device, it was almost fine as before, but the problem is only when downloading from store,

I really appreciate any help,
[image: testing image]

[image: after downloading from store]

Regards,

Comment: please, attach screenshots with images before and after upload to appstore. are images loading from bundle?

Comment: Dear, i tried to attach ScreenShots but i think am not allowed cuz i must get 10 reputation as i think, the images was added manually to resources folder inside the project, and then by coding they are assigned to tableView Cells??!!!

Comment: @user1214314 You should be able to upload images now.

Comment: well, images are included now, plz i need ur feed back!!

Comment: the first shows while am testing, which is supposed to look like, and the second shows after downloading from stores, which is the problem.
Regards,

Comment: Post the code that populates your table view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite likely to be do with floating-point calculation optimization.

When building for release, by default, Xcode will try to fully optimize your code, including making your floating-point calculations more efficient. However, sometimes they can be incorrectly optimized, and this can cause major issues especially with positioning / sizing of views etc.

For me, this happens when building for release + armv6 architecture, and I've had [exactly the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9009883/840973) (only realized when released) before.

Thankfully, there is a way to disable the floating-point optimizations. Here's how:

**Using LLVM GCC 4.2**

1. Click on your project in the files pane on the left
2. Click the project name under `Targets` (as seen below), then click "Build Settings".
3. Search for "thumb" in the search box on the right hand side
4. You should see a setting called "Compile for Thumb" under "LLVM GCC 4.2 - Code Generation". If you don't, it's because you're using the Apple LLVM compiler 3.0 (instructions for that are below).
5. Hover over Release, and click the plus icon.
6. A new option should appear, with a drop-down, select "ARMv6" from the dropdown.
7. Then select "No" for that option. It should now look like below:

[image: Screenshot showing Compile for Thumb setting]

---

**Using Apple LLVM 3.0 Compiler**

1. Follow steps 1 and 2 above.
2. Search for "other c flags" in the search box
3. Follow the same steps above to add a specific configuration for ARMv6 + release.
4. Double-click the box with the flags in, and add the flag `-mno-thumb`. It should now look like below

[image: Disabling Compiile for Thumb for the Apple Compiler]

If it still has issues under the release build after that, you may want to try disabling compile for thumb globally.

Hope that helps.

Comment: man am very thankful, and i really appreciate that briefly reply, i did exactly what u explained above, and my application was updated, hope this will solve my problem, again, am very thankful with my best regards,

Answer (score 1):

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 120; // also custom uitableviewcell should have same height
}
```